# Iterating over nested list

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a list with a nested list returned from my view, something like -

```
[[1, [1, 2, 3]], [2, [2, 3, 4]], [3, [3,4,5]]]
```

I want something like this, which would work in python -

```
for obj in my_list:
    for nested_obj in obj[1]:
        print nested_obj
```

But with the django template system, if I try -

```
{% for obj in data_list %}
    <h2>{{obj.0}}</h2>
    <p>
    {{for nested_obj in obj.1}}
        <h5>{{nested_obj}}</h5>
    {{ endfor }}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I get -

```
Could not parse the remainder: ' nested_obj in obj.1' from 'for nested_obj in obj.1'
```

Why is this?
Thanks!

Edit -
So, that was stupid - I wrote `{{for .... }}` instead of `{% for ... %}`
Thanks @allcaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ for x in ... }}` is causing a TemplateSyntaxError and should be `{% for x in ... %}`.

python manage.py shell

```
from django.template import Template, Context

data_list = [[1, [1, 2, 3]], [2, [2, 3, 4]], [3, [3, 4, 5]]]
template = """
    {% for obj in data_list %}
        Obj {{obj.0}}
        {% for nested_obj in obj.1 %}
            Nested {{nested_obj}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    """

t = Template(template)
c = Context({"data_list": data_list})

print t.render(c)
```

Out:

> ```
>     Obj 1
>
>         Nested 1
>
>         Nested 2
>
>         Nested 3
>
>
>     Obj 2
>
>         Nested 2
>
>         Nested 3
>
>         Nested 4
>
>
>     Obj 3
>
>         Nested 3
>
>         Nested 4
>
>         Nested 5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is working...

```
data_list = [[1, [1, 2, 3]], [2, [2, 3, 4]], [3, [3,4,5]]]

{% for header, remainder in data_list %}
    <h2>a</h2>
    <p>
    {{ for x in remainder }}
        <h5>{{ x }}</h5>
    {{ endfor }}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ' x in remainder' from 'for x in remainder'`

Comment: THen, how do you send the data_list to your template? are you sure it is in the form of a data_list ?

Comment: `{{ for x in ... }}` is causing a `TemplateSyntaxError`. `{% for x in ... %}` does not.

Comment: oh, geez, of course. Didn't notice that you were'nt using the '{% %}' syntax